# TFS 2012 Run Automated Tests on different Agent

Tags: visual-studio-2015, tfs, automated-tests

We don't have a virtual environment in my workplace, I work for a very small company.

All they have here is TFS 2012, not 2015 or 2017.  Though we do have Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise for the developer computers.

I am wondering if TFS 2012 has the neccessary features to run automated tests aftr builds on a physical PC rather than a virtual?

I don't see any options in the build definitions here to select a test target PC.  I don't want to use the build agent as the test agent as that is a pointless test (visual studio's installed on the build server).

How on earth can I use TFS 2012 to run automated tests on a different agent than the build agent?

Comment: You really should upgrade your TFS to 2017 and explore using the cloud for machenes, Azure and AWS provide good features...

Comment: I have to convince management to spend the money:

Comment: I have to convince management to spend the money.  Our app server would need a hardware upgrade, our database server would need hardware and software upgrade.  It's a project in itself.  I have asked, but was informed it's out of budget right now.

Comment: 1) if it runs 2012 it will run 2017 - so no new hardware requirement. 2) fair that you may need to upgrade windows and/or sql server, however the licensing (depending in your configuration) is covered.

Comment: If they can't afford to do anything then they can't afford to run TFS properly at all. Give me a call and we can get your migrated to VSTS  and you will always have the latest version...

Comment: Our dev lead and I concur that the server we run results in slow performance for TFS 2012 as it is, even without any Sharepoint Reporting or other advanced features.  I don't doubt it would run 2017, but it would be unbearably slow.

Comment: As far as SQL Server they run 2008 here, so TFS 2017 is a no go as it requires a more recent version (2014?).

Comment: VSTS was brought up by myself as an alternative, and unfortunately management does not trust cloud services with client data a the moment. It's a hard sell.  Been there already.

Comment: Lol, but they are willing to store their data (the corporate asset) in an aging server with limited support and poor maintenance. Probably stored in a data center that significantly less secure than Azure or AWS. I guess if the business wants to shoot themselves in the foot then that's their call...

Comment: Convincing corporate to invest in IT is always a challenge, particularly when the decision-makers are business majors not software engineers.  They want security, but they have to manage that within their budget.  Performance comes  a distant second.

Answer (score 2):

You could install test agents on your target PC and run your tests on test agent using **LabDefaultTemplate**.

1. Install **Test Controller** and **Test Agent** on the target PC. Configure that controller to register to your 
   TFS collection and make your test agent to connect to your test controller.
2. In MTM, connect to your team project, [add a Lab Enviroment](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee390842(v=vs.110).aspx) and add that test agent to this Lab Environment.
3. Create a build definition to build your test project.
4. Create another build definition choosing LabDefaultTemplate. In this build definition, choosing that Lab Environment you created in Step2. Choosing the build definition you create in Step3. Then trigger this build definition, it will run the tests on your test agent(your target machine).

Comment: Great!  Thank you!  I hadn't thought to look at the lab template at all.  No idea why... I guess I am just so accustomed to using the one I wrote already.